# What are some good example open source Ruby projects that use Cucumber and RSpec well?

Tags: ruby, tdd, rspec, cucumber

What are some good example open source Ruby projects that use Cucumber and RSpec well?

Update: While the suggestions below where quite impressive, I wanted to see how others are using RSpec and Cucumber to drive product development.

Comment: Not all of them uses Cucumber and RSpec, though I found this useful - http://www.opensourcerails.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find it really nice that the RSpec project is tested with both Cucumber and RSpec itself:

- https://github.com/rspec/rspec-core/tree/master/features
- https://github.com/rspec/rspec-core/tree/master/spec

Cucumber is also self-hosted test-wise:

- https://github.com/aslakhellesoy/cucumber/tree/master/features

I've also found it very useful that Aruba, a library of steps for testing CLI apps with Cucumber, is itself tested with Cucumber:

- https://github.com/aslakhellesoy/aruba/tree/master/features

Comment: Isn't a little worrying that all these examples of using RSpec or cucumber are so directly related to RSpec or Cucumber? It seems a little incestuous.

Answer (score 3):

From Quora:

Teng Siong Ong, Ruby, Python, etc.

https://github.com/teambox/teambox

Answer (score 1):

[RubySpec](https://github.com/rubyspec/rubyspec) is a rather ambitious effort to write specs for the Ruby language.

Comment: That uses mspec, rather than rspec.

Comment: 12 yrs later.. Andrew is right, the syntax of https://github.com/ruby/spec is similar to RSpec(ver 2) but it's not technically native RSpec.